# Kotlin-Swift interop issue: ArrayList has wrong count value when passed as NSMutableArray from Swift Code for Release builds

Tags: swift, kotlin, interop, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

Let's assume a KMP Project which is set to have a Sample iOS app in which a KMP module's output framework is added as a dependency.

I am having a function `sampleFuncForStringArrayList(names: ArrayList<String>)` in KMP module which prints count and iterates and print ArrayList items.

When I call this function from the iOS sample app, I am getting index out of bound exception
because NSMutableArray `count` which is **2 in iOS app environment**, has `count` as **24576 when received as ArrayList in KMP module**.

This issue happens only with releaseFramework. **debugFramework** works fine.

```
//Swift
let namesStringList = NSMutableArray(array: ["Alice", "Bob"])
print("NSMutableArray COUNT : \(namesStringList.count)")
Main().sampleFuncForStringArrayList(names: namesStringList)


//Kotlin
public class Main {
    public fun sampleFuncForStringArrayList(names: ArrayList<String>){
        println("names.isNullOrEmpty() ${names.isNullOrEmpty()}")
        println("names.count ${names.count()}")
        names.forEach {
            println("Hello $it")
        }
    }
}
```

Expected Output

```
NSMutableArray COUNT : 2
names.isNullOrEmpty() false
names.count 2
Hello Alice
Hello Bob
```

Actual Output:

```
NSMutableArray COUNT : 2
names.isNullOrEmpty() false
names.count 24576
CRASH
```

[- CRASH -](https://gist.github.com/jolasjoe/43ccae4d305a08f7e0f0361b1a0511b5)

Sample Project ZIP: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SgmW4hfeWaEeD3vcidnZ81Q9vMJsU9zJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: looks like a pure KMP bug

Comment: Would it crash if instead of `String` it would be some other [primitive] type?

Comment: Yes. I tried with Int and simple enum. Both had the same result.

Comment: What kotlin version are you using?

Comment: Didn't tested your project, but with my KMM setup and kotlin 1.4.10, even if I've used `MutableList` and not `ArrayList` [ref](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/objc_interop.html), I've your expected behaviour in both my cases.

Comment: Kotlin 1.4.10. I got same crash for 1.4.0 too.

Comment: Update: The issue happens only with releaseFramework. May be you're trying with debugFramework.

Comment: I’ve tested only in debug mode, yes.

Comment: @JolasJoe I got no problem if I use `MutableList` even with a release framework. With debug framework I got `count = 0` but not a crash. Did you try to use `MutableList` as the right type for kotlin/swift interop? `fun sampleFuncForStringMutableList(names: MutableList<String>)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tried with my KMM setup (using cocoapods) and even with a release build I got the right expected behaviour but I've used the right [kotlin/swift interop mapping](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/objc_interop.html) type `MutableList`

```kotlin
fun sampleFuncForStringMutableList(names: MutableList<String>) {
    println("names.isNullOrEmpty() ${names.isNullOrEmpty()}")
    println("names.count ${names.count()}")
    names.forEach {
        println("Hello $it")
    }
}
```

With `ArrayList` I see an empty array and then a crash (different from debug build where I see your expected behaviour too).

```swift
let namesStringList = NSMutableArray(array: ["Alice", "Bob"])
print("NSMutableArray COUNT : \(namesStringList.count)")
Main().sampleFuncForStringArrayList(names: namesStringList)
Main().sampleFuncForStringMutableList(names: namesStringList)
```

```sh
NSMutableArray COUNT : 2
names.isNullOrEmpty() true
names.count 0
names.isNullOrEmpty() false
names.count 2
Hello Alice
Hello Bob
```

So I suggest you to use the right mapping type and not another one.